# How to let users view a public folder's calendar content without letting them see details within appointments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, public-folders

Giving the `Reviewer` status lets a user view a calendar, but it also lets them view detailed information within each appointments.

I'm trying to set some user so they can only see the calendar and its appointments without being able to open the appointments and see the detailed information within them. Can it be achieved?

I can only set the "read" part of rights to `None` or `All details`, there's no in-between.

I already tried setting the read rights to none with the `folder visible` checkbox checked, but it won't let the user open the calendar at all since it has no read rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with out-of-box Public Folders. Have you considered setting up the calendar in a separate account (like a user, but effectively a Resource Account), then for this dedicated mailbox/user, configure so that it automatically responds to meeting requests. Then you will have the option to configure permissions so that only "Free/Busy" status is permitted. And users will be able to easily update the calendar by sending meeting requests/invites.

Comment: I didn't consider this option. I will look into it and see if the departement likes the idea. Thank you.